# In dplyr how do you filter to remove NA values from columns in a character vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, na, across

I'd like to remove rows with `NA` in any one of the columns in a vector of column names.

Here's a simplified example with just a couple of columns.

```
data <- structure(list(sample_id = c("2023.01.12_2", "2023.01.12_27", 
"2023.01.12_27", "2023.01.12_3", "2023.01.12_27", "2023.01.12_27", 
"2023.01.12_4", "2023.01.12_27", "2023.01.12_27", "2023.01.12_5"
), group = c("Unedited", "Rob", "Rob", "Partial_promoter", "Rob", 
"Rob", "Promoter_and_ATG", "Rob", "Rob", "ATG"), day = c(6, NA, 
NA, 6, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 6), x = c(114.243333333333, 115.036666666667, 
115.073333333333, 114.41, 116.11, 116.163333333333, 113.426666666667, 
116.15, 117.253333333333, 113.46)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

cols <- c("group", "day")
```

I've tried a few ways, but can't get it working. This one below seems to work.

```
data %>%
filter(across(.cols = cols, .fns = ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

But when I try reversing it, to select the columns that are `NA` (for QC purposes I want to keep them, but just separately) I get nothing:

```
data %>%
  filter(across(.cols = cols, .fns = ~ is.na(.x)))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `data |> filter(if_all(everything(), ~!is.na(.x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `drop_na` and `any_of` based on the columns you mentioned. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
cols <- c("group", "day")
library(tidyr)
data |>
  drop_na(any_of(cols))
#>      sample_id            group day        x
#> 1 2023.01.12_2         Unedited   6 114.2433
#> 2 2023.01.12_3 Partial_promoter   6 114.4100
#> 3 2023.01.12_4 Promoter_and_ATG   6 113.4267
#> 4 2023.01.12_5              ATG   6 113.4600
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, and how about the opposite - keeping only rows with NA in the selected columns?

Comment: Hi @Mike, this is an option: `data |> filter(if_any(cols, ~ is.na(.x)))
`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `if_any` for filtering when `is.na` condition is met by either `group` or `day`

```
 data %>%
   filter(if_any(.cols = cols, .fns = ~is.na(.x)))
      sample_id group day        x
1 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 115.0367
2 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 115.0733
3 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 116.1100
4 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 116.1633
5 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 116.1500
6 2023.01.12_27   Rob  NA 117.2533
```

Also there is a `if_all` helper to check if all `cols` meet the contidion of being `na`:

```
 data %>%
       filter(if_any(.cols = cols, .fns = ~is.na(.x)))
```

This retuns none result because only `day` meets the contion.

Since the warning about using `across` inside `filter`, you can replace your first filter by:

```
data %>%
  filter(if_all(.cols = cols, .fns = ~ !is.na(.x)))
```